# Distributing Python script which depends on a package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, pip

I wrote a script which makes use of Selenium, I installed Selenium through pip. Is there a way that I can distribute this script to others without having them to install Selenium through pip?

I was looking at:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads

Would it help if I included the source distribution of Selenium from PyPI in my project folder? So that people just would have to click on the source distribution's `install.py` to install Selenium?

Comment: You can't package another package with your package, unless you want to include all of its source/binaries with your script. You *can* install `selenium` and any other dependencies when your script is being installed by a package manager like `pip` however, so that `pip install your_pkg` installs all the missing/outdated dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `setuptools` and use the `install_requires` keyword.

Like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # options
    install_requires = ['selenium'],
)
```

See the tutorial [here](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)

Then when they install your package/module using pip, selenium will also be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a real answer to this problem:

```
import os
import sys

os.system("python get-pip.py")

try:
    import pip
except ImportError:
    input('Could not install pip, please enter any key to quit this window.')
    sys.exit()


def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('selenium')
```

I did it like that, it makes use of pip. Now people just can execute that script and both `pip` and `selenium` gets installed for them, however I'm unsure whether this is the right way to do it or not.